# MySQL won't insert all of the value

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is that MySQL cuts off one of my values while trying to insert. EVEN, if I try from phpmyadmin. I am trying to insert this: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ut leo vitae elit consectetur vestibulum vitae sit amet ante. In sollicitudin mi nec blandit varius.` But, it only inserts this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ut leo vitae elit consectetur ves
```

And it gives me an error:

```
Warning: #1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'date' at row 1
```

I am pretty sure that is something else. Please help me!

Comment: Can you share your table structure and the insert statement you're using?

Comment: Show the query you are trying to execute, your date column seems not null , and you are trying to insert null, or non-integer which is causing the problem.

Comment: The string column is chopped, most likely simply because its width definition is limited. That is not an error, there must be something completely independent when inserting into another column.

Comment: with the information you have provided its quite difficult to answer the question so for me your question is vague

Comment: Unless you post your table structure it is hard to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like echo_Me said the varchar cut it off, even though I've set it to VARCHAR(255). I fixed it by changing it to TEXT, with no limit!

Answer (score 0):

you are giving to that column `VARCHAR(94)` just increase it to `VARCHAR(200)` or whatever you want.